# How to get data from @attributes in json/xml with PHP

Tags: php, json, xml

I have all of the JSON data in @attributes and want to extract it to variables using PHP. 
What i am trying:

```
$url = "http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("Error..");
$json = json_encode($xml, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$decode_json = json_decode($json);
$match = $decode_json->match[0];
print_r($match);
```

Here is the output i get using above code: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3zbq-62w0 
 Any help will be appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: you can convert the result to array and then use array

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `attributes` function that comes with the `simple_xml` library. It returns a `SimpleXMLElement` which implements the `Traversable` interface which means you can iterate through:

```
<?php
$url = "http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("Error..");
$match_attributes = $xml->match->attributes();

foreach ($match_attributes as $k => $v) {
    printf('%s => %s<br />', $k, $v);
}
?>
```

It's easy to get data now.

```
id => 4
type => T20
srs => Bangladesh tour of Sri Lanka, 2017
mchDesc => SL vs BAN
mnum => 1st T20I
vcity => Colombo
vcountry => Sri Lanka
grnd => R.Premadasa Stadium
inngCnt => 1
datapath => http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/match/2017/2017_SL_BAN/SL_BAN_APR04/
```

Comment: this is only providing the first match values, how to get complete data ... ?

Answer (score -1):

@Sukhchain Singh simply try below one:

```
<?php
    $yourArray = json_encode($yourJson, true);
    /* suppose you got $yourArray = array(
                            "@attributes" => array(
                            "id" => 4,
                            "type" => "T20",
                            "srs" => "Bangladesh tour of Sri Lanka, 2017",
                            "mchDesc" => "SL vs BAN",
                            "mnum" => "1st T20I",
                            "vcity" => "Colombo",
                            "vcountry" => "Sri Lanka",
                            "grnd" => "R.Premadasa Stadium",
                            "inngCnt" => 1,
                            "datapath" => "http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/match/2017/2017_SL_BAN/SL_BAN_APR04/"
                        )
                    );
         */
extract($yourArray["@attributes"]); // it will extract all the element as a variable
echo $id;
```

Comment: Can you please sync this code with my code? How can i do that?

Comment: Got this error:
E_WARNING :  type 2 -- Illegal string offset '@attributes' -- at line 6
Exception: Only variables can be passed by reference
Code: 
`$url = "http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("Error..");
$yourArray = json_encode($xml, true);
extract($yourArray["@attributes"]);
echo $id;`